# Image display fine, saving it returns "server error"

Tags: php, image, qr-code

Im outputting a QR code in php using this code:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$content = imagecreatefrompng("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=120x120&chl=".Crypt::encrypt($username)."&chld=|0");
echo file_get_contents(imagepng($content));
imagedestroy($content);
```

It's displayed fine, however... when I save the file to my local computer in chrome, chrome gives me the error "Serverproblem". Downloading the file in Internet Explorer, gives me a file that's corrupt, what am I doing wrong :)?

The crypt class is from Laravel, which the code is being run under.

Opening the file I downloaded from Internet Explorer in notepad, this is its contents.

```
From: "Saved by Internet Explorer 11"
Subject: 
Date: Fri, 17 Jan 2014 12:52:17 +0100
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="Windows-1252"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Location: http://site/api/qr/niel3445?key=1235234764
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.3.9600.16384

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD><META content=3D"IE=3D5.0000" =
http-equiv=3D"X-UA-Compatible">

<META http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; =
charset=3Dwindows-1252">
<META name=3D"GENERATOR" content=3D"MSHTML 11.00.9600.16476"></HEAD>
<BODY><IMG src=3D""></BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Crypt has nothing to do with it. If crypt failed, the output wouldn't be displayed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine solved the problem. The problem lies within Laravel, the following code made it work:

```
$content = imagecreatefrompng("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=120x120&chl=".Crypt::encrypt($username)."&chld=|0");
imagepng($content);
return Response::make('', 200, array('content-type' => 'image/png', 'Content-Disposition' => 'filename="'.$username.'.png"'));
```

Why Response needs an empty string doesn't make sense to me, but it's working ^^